# Send outlook email through proxy server in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

How can I send an outlook email through a proxy server?

I am working for a company on a project, and I want my laravel project able to send the email. But, the company is protected by a proxy server and whenever I want to send email, I will get below kind of error:

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io >:stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

my .env file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST={proxy_address}
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******@{Company_domain}.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=***************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=''

HTTPS_PROXY = {proxy_name}:{proxy_password}@{proxy_address}:{port}
```

Comment: Check with your company IT departement, we can't help you with your company network without knowing the rules of it.

Comment: My company’s IT department is not very familiar with programming and proxies. Are there any rules and details I should know and ask them? Sorry for asking this weird question but really having no idea

Comment: ask who put it place the proxies